# Lower Bound on the Probability an LWE Matrix is Primitive

Tags: lattice-crypto

For positive integers $q, n, m>n$, how do we derive the lower bound $Pr[A\cdot \mathbb Z_q^m = \mathbb Z_q^n] \geq 1 - \frac{1}{q^{m-n}}$ for a uniformly random matrix $A \in \mathbb Z_q^{n \times m}$?

I know this probability is equivalent to the probability that each row has gcd 1 with q, $gcd(a_{i,1}, \dots, a_{i,m}, q) = 1$. Also, there is a lower bound on the totient function, $\varphi(q) \geq \sqrt q/\sqrt 2$, but this hasn't led me to a solution for the bound we want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking it.

**Hint**

The event in which $A\cdot \mathbb Z_q^m \neq \mathbb Z_q^n$ is the event in which the matrix $A$ has a rank defect, which is "contained" in the event in which (say) the first row is a linear combination of the other rows.
Now, what's the probability of the latter event?

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that the formula you're trying to prove isn't true in general.

One example where it is not true is $q=8, m=2, n=1$.

In this case, the random matrix $A$ consists of two values; it generates the entire space $\mathbb Z_q^n$ iff at least one of the those two values is odd; this happens with probability $\frac{3}{4}$.

However, your formula says that the probability is $\ge 1 - \frac{1}{q^{m-n}} = \frac{7}{8}$; obviously, this is not true.

Now, it is true if we restrict $q$ to be prime.

The easiest way I can think of to show that is to derive the exact probability

$$Pr[A\cdot \mathbb Z_q^m = \mathbb Z_q^n] = 1 - \sum_{i = m-n+1}^m \frac{1}{q^i}$$

(which can be done by simulating the first $n$ iterations of Gaussian Elimination; if any step fails (and step $i$ will fail with probability $\frac{1}{q^{m-i}}$), then we can generate a postimage that cannot be produced with that random matrix; if all step fails, then for any possible postimage, we can produce a preimage).

Then, we just note that this exact probability is $\ge$ to the given approximation.